# Different environment variables with ssh or kubectl exec

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers

We have a service in our cluster that we call via ssh (test environment etc.). In this container we have different environment variables when we connect with ssh or we connect with kubectl.

Can someone explain me what else is set here with the kubectl exec command?

As an example a small excerpt from both environments.

**kubectl exec: (printenv | grep KU)**

```
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.4.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.4.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.4.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.4.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
```

**ssh into the same container: (printenv | grep KU)**

```
dev-xxxxx:~$ printenv | grep KU
dev-xxxxx:~$
```

Comment: are you sure you logged into a same machine or `IP`.

Comment: Is the container running an ssh daemon, or are you using `kubectl exec`?

Comment: I am sure it is the same container and yes it is running an SSH daemon.

Answer (score 3):

The `kubectl exec` command allows you to remotely run arbitrary commands inside an existing container of a pod. `kubectl exec` isn’t much different from using `SSH` to execute commands on a remote system. `SSH` and `kubectl` should both work well with 99% of CLI applications. The only difference I could find when it comes to environment variables is that:

- `kubectl` will always set the environment variables provided to the container at startup
- `SSH` relies mostly on the system login shell configuration (but can also accept user’s environment via [PermitUserEnvironment or SendEnv/AcceptEnv](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command))

Answering your question:

> Can someone explain me what else is set here with the kubectl exec
> command?

They should result with the same output (assuming that you have typed both commands correctly and execute them on the same container).

Below you will find some useful resources regarding the `kubectl exec` command:

- [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)
- [kubectl-commands#exec docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)
- [How does 'kubectl exec' work?](https://erkanerol.github.io/post/how-kubectl-exec-works/)

**EDIT:**

If you wish to learn some more regarding the differences between `kubectl exec` and `SSH` I recommend [this article](https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-vs-kubectl/). It covers the topics of:

- Authn/z
- Shell UX
- Non-shell features, and
- Performance

Comment: OP asks the diffference. Assuming he knows what you have explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a NodePort to SSH into a container running inside a Kubernetes pod, the environment variables defined within the Kubernetes deployment won't be automatically available in your SSH session. This is because SSHing into a container using a NodePort involves connecting directly to the container's network namespace, bypassing Kubernetes' usual environment management.

In this scenario, if you need to access specific environment variables within the container when SSHing via NodePort, you'll need to manually source the appropriate initialization files that define those variables.